# find all descendants of a parent using recursive merge function or something else?

Tags: r

So I have a large data.frame. First column is parent, second column is child.

- 1 -> 2
- 1 -> 3
- 2 -> 3
- 2 -> 4
- 2 -> 5
- 6 -> 7
- 6 -> 8
- 7 -> 9

and so on..

Problem: For a subsample of parents, I want to find all their descendants. That is, for a set of parents, I need their children, grandchildren, etc...

Example of output: Using the numbers above, if I wanted to get a data.frame containing the descendants of 1, I'd get

- 1 -> 2
- 1 -> 3
- 2 -> 3
- 2 -> 4
- 2 -> 5

But not below since these are not descendants of 1. They come from a different family.

- 6 -> 7
- 6 -> 8
- 7 -> 9

What would be the best way to do this?

A recursive function of self-joins using merge function? If so, any good examples?

Or is there a package with this functionality already?

Comment: Could you show us an example of the result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want split but I'm not entirely sure I'm clear on what you want:

```
DF <- data.frame(par=rep(1:4, each=4), child = 5:20, granchild = 21:36)
split(DF, DF$par)
```